# Function app not being displayed on Azure VSCode

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm deploying a function app, however it doesn't get displayed on my Azure VSCode extension under the subscription resources:

[image: VSCode extension]

[image: Not appearing when trying to deploy function]

[image: Azure]

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalled Azure VSCode extensions
- Cleaned VSCode cache / sign out from Azure account + sign in again

Comment: Did you created function app successfully in portal?

Comment: Try to install azure functions extensions in the visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

> Function app not being displayed on Azure VSCode

- Try refreshing the Azure extension in Visual Studio Code. Sometimes, resources might not appear due to caching issues.
- Ensure that signed in to the correct Azure subscription in Visual Studio Code. Sometimes, might be signed in with different credentials or subscriptions.
- Ensure to install the azure functions extension in visual studio code like below:

[image]

- Make sure the function app successfully deployed while creating in portal.

[image]

- After created the function, Refresh the resources, I am able to see the function app in visual studio code. check below:

[image]

Check the profile in visual studio code for azure logged in successfully or not like below:

[image]